# Extract sentences of a character vector satisfying two conditions in R

Tags: r, paste

Lets say we have a full text file loaded into R as a character vector.  I'm looking for a code that will pull out all text between two "."'s as long as between those two periods, there exists "and the" and at least one "%".

```
character <- as.character("Walmart stocks remained the same.  Sony reported an increase, and the percent was posted at 1.0%. And the google also remained the same.  And the percent of increase for Best Buy was 2.5%.")
```

Taking a look at this short example, I am hoping for an output somewhere along the lines of

```
[1] Sony reported an increase, and the percent was posted at 1.0%.
[2] And the percent of increase for Best Buy was 2.5%.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick solution:

```
library(magrittr)
"Walmart stocks remained the same.  Sony reported an increase, and the percent was posted at 1.0%. And the google also remained the same.  And the percent of increase for Best Buy was 2.5%." %>%
  ## split the string at the sentence boundaries
  gsub("\\.\\s", "\\.\t", .) %>%
  strsplit("\\t") %>% unlist() %>%
  ## keep only sentences that contain "and the" (irrespective of case)
  grep("and the", x = ., value = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE) %>%
  ## keep only the sentences that end with %.
  grep("%\\.$", x = ., value = TRUE) %>%
  ## remove leading white spaces
  gsub("^\\s?", "", x = .)
```

Comment: Worked like a charms! only had issues in my application when using a large text file from the web where sentences would get cut off and continue on the next line since they were too long.  So I made the whole text file into a single character vector first by inserting paste in front of my readLines function like: `paste(readLines("websiteurl.txt"), collapse = " ") %>%`